# Getting TypeError when attempting to migrate database in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm currently trying to automatically generate an id number and store it as a default value in the database:

```
class EmployeeProfile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def generate_id(self):
        first_initial = self.first_name[0].upper()
        second_initial = self.last_name[0].upper()
        id_number = first_initial + second_initial + str(random.randint(1000000, 9999999))

        if not EmployeeProfile.objects.filter(employee_id=id_number).exists():
            return id_number

    employee_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=11, default=generate_id)
```

What I'm getting is a "TypeError: generate_id() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'". I've looked through the Django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#default and it says I can use a callable for the default value in the model, which is what I did but I'm getting this type error when I attempt to migrate the database. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: it can be a callable object, but not a method on the model (there is no way to provide `self`, as you're seeing).  You should override the `save()` method instead.

Comment: That worked great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user thebjorn, I merely had to override the save method instead of trying to call the method.

```
def save(self):
    first_initial = self.first_name[0].upper()
    second_initial = self.last_name[0].upper()
    id_number = first_initial + second_initial + str(random.randint(1000000, 9999999))

    if not EmployeeProfile.objects.filter(employee_id=id_number).exists():
        self.employee_id = id_number
        super(EmployeeProfile, self).save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried some stuff and this seems to migrate well:

```
class EmployeeProfile(models.Model):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def generate_id():
    first_initial = 'a'
    second_initial = 'b'
    id_number = 2
    return id_number

employee_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=11, default=generate_id)
```

So it seems you cannot pass "self" to generate_id().

Can't you add the employee_id later in the view? Thats the way i'd do it. If you do it like this you can edit the values before saving:

```
if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.employee_id = <STUFF>
    instance.save()
    messages.success(request, "Stamp changes saved.")
    return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
```

**EDIT:** I tried some more stuff and you can try to remove self from generate_id(), then migrate, then add it back in. It seems to work. Even modifying the model afterwards and migrating again was no problem.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer. thebjorn said I just had to override the save function and it worked just fine. I will post the solution here in a moment.

Comment: Ah, so like the one i suggested in the middle? No problem, i try to learn by reading other's questions and trying to answer some of them.

Comment: Yes, your answer is similar, but your saves on the view side while thebjorn's answer saves on the on the model side. Bjorn replied to my question right before you submitted your answer.